# Function DeleteNonMatched(ByVal Sheetname As Worksheet) not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I have this function, which accepts a sheetname and makes the sheetname passed active. But for some reason it is not making the "Actives" sheet acttive.

Full code:

```
Public wb As Workbook
Public ws As String
Public filterValue() As String
Public My_Range As Range
Public i As Integer
Public CCount As Long

Sub test()
 'Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim FilterCriteria As String
    'Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim Sheetname As String
    'Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    'Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Sheets("Input Sheet").Select
    NumRows = Sheets("Input Sheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ReDim filterValue(1 To NumRows)
    For j = 1 To NumRows
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(j, 1).Value) Then
            filterValue(j) = Cells(j, 1).Value
         End If
    Next j


    DeleteNonMatched ("Actives")

    'For k = LBound(filterValue) + 1 To UBound(filterValue)


          'End If
    'Next k


End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)

    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
Function DeleteNonMatched(ByVal Sheetname As Worksheet)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next

    Sheets(Sheetname).Select

    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Actives")
    ws.Activate
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:F" & LastRow(ws))
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
                My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells.Count - 1
                For i = 1 To CCount
                My_Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                i = i + 1
                On Error GoTo 0
                'If CCount <> 0 Then
                'MsgBox CCount
                Next i
 On Error GoTo 0

End Function


----Function not working-----------

Function DeleteNonMatched(ByVal Sheetname As Worksheet)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next

    Sheets(Sheetname).Select

    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Actives")
    ws.Activate
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:F" & LastRow(ws))
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
                My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells.Count - 1
                For i = 1 To CCount
                My_Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                i = i + 1
                On Error GoTo 0
                'If CCount <> 0 Then
                'MsgBox CCount
                Next i
 On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` often functions as `On Error Hide Bug`. Why not delete those lines and fix the resulting errors? Also, it would help if you give a [mcve] with an emphasis on "minimal". There seems to be a lot of code which isn't directly relevant to your actual problem.

Comment: It's just this part of the code which is not working. I need it to activate the "Actives" sheet and delete the rows which don't match the filter criteria.

Function DeleteNonMatched(ByVal Sheetname As String)

Comment: Do you have a worksheet actually called `Actives` in your workbook? If you think you do, double check the spelling and look for extra spaces.

Comment: There is the sheet "Actives"

Comment: Why do you need a function?

Comment: `DeleteNonMatched(ByVal Sheetname As Worksheet)` your function expects a worksheet  object, not a string.